# <g:form> in grails missing when rendered in firefox

Tags: html, grails, gsp

Do anyone have any idea about this?I have a template _contact.gsp rendered as a column in the right side of a view.Following is its code:

```
 <div id="contact-${contactType.id}" class="contact" style="${contactType.isPrimary == 1 ? '' : 'display: none;'}">

<g:hiddenField name="contact-${contactType?.id}.id" value="${contact?.id}"/>

<g:applyLayout name="form/input">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.organization.name"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.organizationName</content>


<g:form  id="form-org" action="search">// this tag is not rendered


          <input type="text" id="Company" value="search for..." name="Company" class="field">        

</g:form>        

</g:applyLayout><div> 

<label style="visibility:hidden" for="PRIVATE" class="lb">-------------------------------------</label><a onclick="$('#form-org').submit()" style="display:inline"><img src="/jbilling/images/icon-search.gif"></a></div>

 <g:applyLayout name="form/input">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.first.name"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.firstName</content>
    <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.firstName" value="${contact?.firstName}" />
</g:applyLayout>

<g:applyLayout name="form/input">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.last.name"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.lastName</content>
    <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.lastName" value="${contact?.lastName}" />
</g:applyLayout>

<g:applyLayout name="form/text">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.phone.number"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.phoneCountryCode</content>
    <span>
        <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.phoneCountryCode" value="${contact?.phoneCountryCode}" maxlength="3" size="2"/>
        -
        <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.phoneAreaCode" value="${contact?.phoneAreaCode}" maxlength="5" size="3"/>
        -
        <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.phoneNumber" value="${contact?.phoneNumber}" maxlength="10" size="8"/>
    </span>
</g:applyLayout>

<g:applyLayout name="form/input">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.email"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.email</content>
    <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.email" value="${contact?.email}" />
</g:applyLayout>

<g:applyLayout name="form/input">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.address1"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.address1</content>
    <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.address1" value="${contact?.address1}" />
</g:applyLayout>

<g:applyLayout name="form/input">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.address2"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.address2</content>
    <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.address2" value="${contact?.address2}" />
</g:applyLayout>

<g:applyLayout name="form/input">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.city"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.city</content>
    <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.city" value="${contact?.city}" />
</g:applyLayout>

<g:applyLayout name="form/input">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.state"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.stateProvince</content>
    <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.stateProvince" value="${contact?.stateProvince}" />
</g:applyLayout>

<g:applyLayout name="form/input">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.zip"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.postalCode</content>
    <g:textField class="field" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.postalCode" value="${contact?.postalCode}" />
</g:applyLayout>

<g:applyLayout name="form/select">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.country"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.countryCode</content>

    <g:select name="contact-${contactType?.id}.countryCode"
              from="${CountryDTO.list()}"
              optionKey="code"
              optionValue="${{ it.getDescription(session['language_id']) }}"
              noSelection="['': message(code: 'default.no.selection')]"
              value="${contact?.countryCode}"/>
</g:applyLayout>

<g:applyLayout name="form/checkbox">
    <content tag="label"><g:message code="prompt.include.in.notifications"/></content>
    <content tag="label.for">contact-${contactType?.id}.include</content>
    <g:checkBox class="cb checkbox" name="contact-${contactType?.id}.include" checked="${contact?.include}"/>
</g:applyLayout>
</div>
```

When i ran this code in firefox, the view is rendered fine, except the form tag is missing.I checked this in firebug when the button clicked returned no response.The firebug shows the source as follows:
**source of the view rendered in firefox corresponding to the applyLayout tag containing the form tag**

```
<div class="row">  //notice this;form is absent  
<label for="contact-20.organizationName">Organization Name</label>
<div class="inp-bg ">

          <input type="text" class="field" name="Company" value="search for..." id="Company">        

</div>
```

Because of this conversion from form tag to div tag, my button is not working. Plz help to prevent this conversion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a `g:form` is not rendered by Firefox, but by Grails in the server, which will send an HTML `form` to the browser. But you should know that browsers ignore nested forms, and I'm guessing that is the case here.

Grails probably *is* rendering the tag and the browser is ignoring it because it's inside another form.

You can check if that is the case viewing the source with right clicking the page and choosing `View Page Source` -- that will show the exact output from Grails.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable info...:) you are right when looking page source i can see the form tag...Then can you tell me whether there is a way to render nested forms...?

Comment: Unfortunately, HTML does not allow for nested forms, as it is [shown here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/) (Ctrl-F "Nested forms"). I think your options are: 1) make several little forms each with its own action and variables 2) use one big form with only one action and several named submit buttons, and put some logic in the action to decide what to do according to the name of the submit button that was used.

Comment: In your case, I think I'd go with several little forms with different actions, because you seem to want really different things and it makes for a good separation. Also, as you seem to be using layouts for rendering form fields, you may want to check out [Grails Fields plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/fields).

Comment: is there any way to pass textField input within params without submitting forms in grails?

Comment: Not really, `textField` needs a form. There is probably a better way to do what you want. You may want to ask a new question explaining what is the problem you want to solve, what user interface you are planning and how you tried.